# R: Error Data is too long

Tags: raster, r, error

I have a R Script, that is extracting some information from a dem Raster through a multiprocess step. At one Point the standart deviation of the raster is calculated:

```
std_ras <- sd(ras_smooth[], na.rm = T)
```

which encounters the following error:

```
Error in matrix(v, ncol = nlyr(x)) : data is too long
```

ras_smooth has the Type

```
S4 [29402 x 111195 x 1] (terra::SpatRaster)
```

als Value

```
S4 object of class SpatRaster
```

The same code runs without problems on another Raster. I tried to search the Error, but couldn't find anything that helped me. Does anyone have an idea, what I might do to deal with the error?

Comment: Since you are after statistics for the entire raster, have you tired `terra::global`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As César Arquero Cabral pointed out, the Raster was just too big. Unfortunetly I couldn't get his Answer to work, so I just split the Raster in several smaller parts, which is good enough for what i want to do.

Answer (score 1):

at the end, the raster values will be treated as a chain of values to get this statistics...and there is a limit. Your raster exeds the maximim value of 2^31-1, or about 2.1.
One possible solution is to chunk your raster file to get the statatistics. Something like this:

```
library(raster)
library(terra)
library(ff)

# read your file
r <- rast("test.tif")

cum_sum <- 0
cum_sum_sq <- 0
total_count <- 0

# Define chunk size
chunk_size <- 5000  # Number of rows in each chunk

# Calculate the number of chunks needed
n_chunks <- ceiling(nrow(r) / chunk_size)

for (i in 1:n_chunks) {
    cat("Iteration: ", i, "\n")
    # Calculate row indices for the chunk
    start_row <- (i - 1) * chunk_size + 1
    end_row <- min(i * chunk_size, nrow(r))
    
    # Read the chunk
    chunk <- crop(r, c(1, ncol(r), start_row, end_row))
    
    # Extract values, removing NAs
    vals <- values(chunk)
    valid_vals <- na.omit(vals)
    
    # Update cumulative statistics
    cum_sum <- cum_sum + sum(valid_vals)
    cum_sum_sq <- cum_sum_sq + sum(valid_vals^2)
    total_count <- total_count + length(valid_vals)
}

mean_value <- cum_sum / total_count
variance <- (cum_sum_sq - (cum_sum^2 / total_count)) / (total_count - 1)
sd_value <- sqrt(variance)

sd_value  # This is the standard deviation of the raster values
```

You can test this, and if this is suitable for you, you can tranform this into a function to parallelize it and do it fast.

To check more details see this https://www.modlearth.com/2024/02/12/raster-sd/. Here you will find the a fine process to get this done using parallel in linux (faster processing times).

Comment: And as an alternative, it may be possible to **subsample the raster** - this really depends on your use case, but for a raster of this size it is probably fine.

Comment: Than's a really interesting approach with huge data. I don't know how the subsample will work if it has to get all the values at the raster first.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really believe that the data was too long and thought it was some other mistake from my side, that resulted in this error. I will try the solution and upvote/accept if it works.

Comment: I got another Error, when i tried the solution. Since i am not very experienced with R and can't spent too much time on this, I just decided to split the Input Raster in several parts. Thanks for the Answer, it helped a lot.
Edit: Aparently i cant vote for your answer, as i don't have enough reputation, sorry

Comment: This is a good solution, but not necessary in this case since this is essentially what terra::global does for you in one line and more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeffrey Evens pointed out, you can do

```
terra::global(ras_smooth, "sd", na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you want to use a sample you can do something like this

```
sd(spatSample(ras_smooth, 10000)[,1])
```

Comment: I didn't know that function. I works, this should be the best answer for sure.